# Error on heroku when trying to npm run migrate to deploy my app

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, heroku, error-handling

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku and I'm getting a type error when I npm run migrate on heroku run bash.
The error on the terminal is saying that it's a SQL typo error but I cannot see what is the error. I've tried to change the quotes, but it's not working either. Any help will be welcome.

error:

[image: 1]

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const mysql = require("mysql");

const DB_HOST = process.env.DB_HOST;
const DB_USER = process.env.DB_USER;
const DB_PASS = process.env.DB_PASS;
const DB_NAME = process.env.DB_NAME;

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: DB_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
  user: DB_USER || "root",
  password: DB_PASS || "root",
  database: DB_NAME || "5aday",
  multipleStatements: true
 
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");

  let sql = `DROP TABLE if exists seasons; CREATE TABLE into seasons (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, image VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, list VARCHAR(1000)NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));`;

            `INSERT INTO seasons (image, title,https description, list) VALUES ('https://www.juiceplus.com/content/juiceplusblog/en/2019/3/the-ultimate-fruit-and-vegetable-season-calendar/_jcr_content/par/image.img.jpg/1553178913562.jpg', 'FRUITS AND VEGETABLES AVAILABLE IN WINTER', 'Fruits and vegetables available in the winter months consist of lots of fruits you’d typically associate with Christmas (clementines, cranberries), but also lots of earthy vegetables like turnips, parsnips and leeks. There are some lovely winter warming recipes you can cook with these!', 'Apple
            Pears
            Clementines
            Cranberries
            Dates
            Beetroot
            Brussels sprouts
            Celeriac
            Celery
            Kale
            Leek
            Parsnip
            Turnip
            Sweet potato
            Grapefruit
            Lemon
            Orange
            Rhubarb
            Kiwi
            Passion Fruit
            Pomegranate
            Beetroot
            Brussels sprouts
            Celeriac
            Celery
            Kale
            Leek
            Parsnip
            Turnip
            Sweet potato
            Cauliflower
            Chicory
            Jerusalem artichoke');`

            `INSERT INTO seasons (image, title, description, list) VALUES ('https://www.juiceplus.com/content/juiceplusblog/en/2019/3/the-ultimate-fruit-and-vegetable-season-calendar/_jcr_content/par/image_1056369294.img.jpg/1553178984905.jpg', 'FRUITS AND VEGETABLES AVAILABLE IN SPRING', 'Coming into to spring and lots of fresh spring greens come into season, like watercress, spinach and lettuce. New potatoes also come in the spring, which make for a delicious buttery dish or potato salad with watercress.', 'Grapefruit
            Lemon
            Orange
            Rhubarb
            Passion Fruit
            Pomegranate
            Apricot
            Nectarine
            Brussels sprouts
            Cauliflower
            Chicory
            Jerusalem artichoke
            Spinach
            Watercress
            Purple sprouting broccoli
            New potatoes
            Potatoes
            Carrot
            Lambs lettuce
            Lettuce');`

            `INSERT INTO seasons (image, title, description, list) VALUES ('https://www.juiceplus.com/content/juiceplusblog/en/2019/3/the-ultimate-fruit-and-vegetable-season-calendar/_jcr_content/par/image_1788290349.img.jpg/1553179052619.jpg', 'FRUITS AND VEGETABLES AVAILABLE IN SUMMER', 'As summer comes around, you are certainly not limited in options when it comes to seasonal fruit and vegetables. This is prime time for strawberries, nectarines and apricots – as well as asparagus, peas and runner beans.', 'Apricot
            Blackcurrants
            Gooseberry
            Nectarine
            Rhubarb
            Strawberry
            Tomato
            Cherries
            Raspberry
            Redcurrant
            Watermelon
            Elderberries
            Figs
            Peach
            Asparagus
            Aubergine
            Carrot
            Courgettes
            Lambs lettuce
            Lettuce
            New potatoes
            Peas
            Potatoes
            Runner beans
            Beetroot
            Cavolo Nero
            Fennel
            Celery');`

            `INSERT INTO seasons (image, title, description, list) VALUES ('https://www.juiceplus.com/content/juiceplusblog/en/2019/3/the-ultimate-fruit-and-vegetable-season-calendar/_jcr_content/par/image_1229398484.img.jpg/1553179114378.jpg', 'FRUITS AND VEGETABLES AVAILABLE IN AUTUMN', 'As we turn into autumn, the choice is still plentiful as many vegetables are still giving following the summer months. Sweetcorn is exclusively at it’s best in September and apple and pears come back into full season.', 'Apple
            Blackberry
            Elderberries
            Figs
            Gooseberry
            Nectarine
            Peach
            Redcurrant
            Plum
            Raspberry
            Strawberry
            Tomato
            Pear
            Plum
            Aubergine
            Beetroot
            Cavolo Nero
            Celeriac
            Celery
            Courgettes
            Fennel
            Artichoke
            Lambs lettuce
            Leek
            Peas
            Lettuce
            Runner beans
            Sweetcorn
            Brussels sprouts
            Kale
            Parsnip
            Pumpkin
            Sweet potato ');`
            
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Table creation `seasons` was successful!");

    console.log("Closing...");
  });

  

  con.end();
});
```

Comment: Try to add your error logs as text instead of images. The font disappears to microscopic proportions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont assigne your sql statement to any variable. The first statement is assigned to the sql variable but not the following. Your are terminating the statement after the first create table.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "INTO" too much in the first CREATE TABLE ("CREATE TABLE into seasons") statement if i am seeing this right.

Comment: I have remove the into  in the CREATE TABLE but the error is still there. It's seems to be an error with the 1 st INSERT INTO ....